# Silverlight Togglebutton Set IsPressed state

Tags: c#, silverlight, user-controls

Hello I have a Toggle button in Silverlight.
I want to set its state to "pressed".

First I tried :

```
  btButton.IsPressed = true
```

But that does not work (readonly).
Then I tried :

```
btButton.SetValue(ToggleButton.IsPressedProperty, true);
```

Which also does not work.
How do I accomplish this ? I'd assume it would not be that hard...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [IsChecked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton.ischecked.aspx).  IsPressed tells you whether the mouse or space bar is currently pressing the button.  IsChecked tells you how the button is toggled.

```
 btButton.IsChecked = true;
```

Comment: Well that was easy in hindsight. However you saved me a lot of time and frustration. Thanks.